# How to read sd card sector by sector? (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard, read-write

I need to read all sectors on sd card and create file on phone storage. 
I tried to use UNIX command dd:
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c dd if=/storage/extSdCard of=/storage/emulated/0/data.iso conv=noerror");

but this code has created empty file.

Comment: If you want to read sectors, you need to access the raw device node, not the filesystem mount point.  Needless to say that will be device specific.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Сan i solve my probem using SDK? or i need to use NDK?

Comment: It has nothing to do with either.  You have to read the device node, not the mount point.